# Rename a table used as reference in a another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-database

I have created two PostgreSQL tables tables (the code originates from a Django app):

```
CREATE TABLE "app_book" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(256)
);
CREATE TABLE "app_author" (
    "book_ptr_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES "app_book" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to rename the table `app_book` to `app_item`. Is the following line sufficient, or do I also have to update the REFERENCES in `app_author`? If so, how can I do that?

```
ALTER TABLE app_book RENAME TO app_item;
```

Looking at [this page](http://blog.nanl.de/2011/10/postgresql-altering-table-name-screws-up-references-to-its-primary-key-and-sequence/), I guess that it does not. But the page does not explain how to update the reference.

Comment: What happened when you tried?  Did it work or not?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I did not notice any particular problem. But I am not sure I have tested all the kinds of SQL queries that Django can generate...

Answer (score 1):

See for yourself http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0dd1f/5

The problem described in your link only refers to problems when using Slony.

If you can live with the fact that the sequence "behind" the `id` column does not reflect the name change then everything is fine. If it bothers you, you need to rename the sequence as well. Note that [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) still works.